# OpenIdConnect signin-oidc route not handled by ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect

I am using an external OIDC identity provider to log my users into my webshop. The webshop is being built on ASP.NET MVC with .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I have started using the basic MVC template and adding my authentication code.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();// = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
    });

    var authority = "https://authentication.myOpenIdProvider.com/auth/oauth2/realms/root/realms/test";
    var redirectUri = "http://localhost:8888/signin-oidc";
    var postlogoUri = "http://localhost:8888/signout-callback-oidc";
    var clientId = "MyClientId";
    var clientSecret = "MyClientSecret";

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret,
        Authority = authority,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postlogoUri,
        ResponseType = "code",
        Scope = "openid favorites",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    });
}
```

When i hit login on my page, i get redirected to my authentication provider, also the correct redirectUri is passed.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ... 
}
```

However, after i succesfully authenticate with my external provider and get redirected to my site (currently its just http://localhost:8888/signin-oidc for dev purposes) the route is not handled. I am getting a 404, so something clearly isn't working like it is supposed to do.

I have installed ELMAH and this reports the following exception message:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/signin-oidc' was not found or does not implement IController.

For context: The same works in an ASP.NET Core API, using the same external openid provider with identical configuration.

Comment: The library is deprecated - Microsoft writes:

"UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication is obsolete. Configure OpenIdConnect authentication with AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect in ConfigureServices. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470 for more details."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone browsing this in the future, this is the answer:

`Owin.OpenIdConnect` does not support `"code"` only `ResponseTypes`. You need to set `"id_token"` too. If, for any reason, you cannot do this, you will basically need to implement parts of the spec yourself (mainly by hooking up into the `MessageReceived` Notifications Event).

See this part in the source code of the OpenIdConnect Handler:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/0f6dc4bf2722fb08759da3eacaf38f2a098771bd/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs#L258-L264

Comment: `Authorization Code flow` is now supported in version 4.1.0

Comment: However I still had to handle `MessageReceived` notification and get `id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token` and use those values in `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification when I had authentication ticket available in notification args which I'm not sure is good way but it works when doing authorization cdoe flow with owin library version 4.1.0

Comment: Here are the snippets for whoever needs it https://gist.github.com/harshbaid/89edd39b3304039d7a8a1119b32d90ae

Comment: @HarshBaid Could you provide more than a snippet? I would love to see a proper Configuration, because I am having issue with OIDC too. In case you want to have a look, [my OIDC issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191838/unexpected-behaviour-with-oidc-authentication-on-net-framework?noredirect=1#comment120538456_68191838)

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my Home

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

and similar **RedirectUri** parameter could be add to SignOut too

```
public void SignOut()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```